# How to average hourly values over multiple days with SQL

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have a SQL table (postgreSQL/TimescaleDB) with hourly values, eg:

```
Timestamp               Value
...
2021-02-17 13:00:00     2
2021-02-17 14:00:00     4
...
2021-02-18 13:00:00     3
2021-02-18 14:00:00     3
...
```

I want to get the average values for each hour mapped to today's date in a specific timespan, so something like that:

```
select avg(value)
from table
where Timestamp between '2021-02-10' and '2021-02-20'
group by *hourpart of timestamp*
```

result today (2021-10-08) should be:

```
...
Timestamp               Value
2021-10-08 13:00:00     2.5
2021-10-08 14:00:00     3.5
...
```

If I do the same select tomorrow (2021-10-09) result should change to:

```
...
Timestamp               Value
2021-10-09 13:00:00     2.5
2021-10-09 14:00:00     3.5
...
```

Comment: (1) Please provide queries to create sample table and insert sample data and describe the expected result set according to that sample.  (2) Please inform us if a solution which was tested on SQL Server can help you - might not fit for postgreSQL even so they use the same basic language tsql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by myself:
Solution:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM table."Timestamp") as hour,
avg(table."Value") as average
from table
where Timestamp between '2021-02-10' and '2021-02-20'
group by hour
order by hour;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your query like this:

```sql
select avg(value)
from table
where Timestamp between '2021-02-10' and '2021-02-20'
group by substring(TimeStamp,1,10), substring(TimeStamp,11,9)
```